# Blog large video files video with Javascript

Tags: javascript, blob

Currently, I'm trying put my video file as blob src. Why? Because, I'm trying prevent people hotlinking my video files, I know that it's impossible to keep the links 100% safe, but I'm trying to my best to avoid anything related.

HTML:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
```

Javscript:

```
var videoURL = 'https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/netfix/demo/frag_bunny.mp4';
var video = document.querySelector('video');

var assetURL = videoURL;
// Need to be specific for Blink regarding codecs
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
  //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // closed
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
} else {
  console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}

function sourceOpen (_) {
  //console.log(this.readyState); // open
  var mediaSource = this;
  var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
  fetchAB(assetURL, function (buf) {
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
      mediaSource.endOfStream();
      video.play();
      //console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // ended
    });
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
  });
};

function fetchAB (url, cb) {
  console.log(url);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('get', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function () {
    cb(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

This code works perfectly! But when the video size is higher than 200MB, for example, the video loads until video buffer download ends.

How can I make this code load "piece by piece" instead downloading whole video to after that, make the blob?

Thank you.

Comment: "Why? Because, I'm trying prevent people hotlinking my video files"  Wow, if you think this approach is going to help you in any way at all, you're severely mistaken.

Comment: I'm just trying... JWPlayer is using this way and still working I guess